# Cannot access MySQL database at AWS Tomcat, but works at local Tomcat with all the same war. (JDBS connection error)

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, tomcat, spring-boot

I’m new and try to make my first RESTful services. I made it with Spring Boot, JPA mapped from MySQL database and deployed to Tomcat as war artifact. A MySQL database I also deployed to AWS in RDC service with all default settings. All worked well at local Tomcat. When tried same war artifact at AWS tomcat: deployment with all default settings: web API worked: RESTful services worked with returning java resources, but connection to database not worked when tried to retrieve data from database.
In logs I could see this: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

My settings:
application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://nz4.czzj8lfy5a3f.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com/webshop
# I tryed here also with (and no difference)…com:3306/webshop 
spring.datasource.username=… (secret)
spring.datasource.password=… (secret)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

In build:gradle I have dependences:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
```

example of web api code:

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="customer")
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private Integer customerId;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "email")
...
//getters setters

public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> 
{}

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class CustomerResource {
@Autowired
CustomerRepository customerRepository;
@GetMapping(value = "/customer")
public List< Customer> > getAll() {return customerRepository.findAll();}
...

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebshopApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{SpringApplication.run(WebshopApplication.class, args);}
}
```

Comment: Please check the mysql user have all privileges

Comment: @Sumesh TG Thank you. That is great idea. probably it's the reason for fail. Should I do it in workbench or in AWS settings? I now tryed to do it In MySQL Workbench: I went to "User and privileges", tried to grant all but getting refuse: "mysql privileges error changing account. Access denied for user (using password: YES)".

Comment: Use workbench and check the schema privilege tab

Comment: @Sumesh TG I looked to Shema Privileges. It was empty. I added schema "%" and selected all privileges (selected all checkboxes) : still the same problem: no JDBC connection. Actually should not be difference in connection from local Tomcat or from AWS tomcat?

Comment: Please verify the 'limit to hosts matching' option in login TAB

Comment: @Sumesh TG in 'limit to hosts matching' option I have "%" by default. I'm sorry, I don't understand this option. Could you please tell me what I need to wrire there?

Comment: Check the firewall whether it allows connection from remote machine from mysql default port 3306 if not add rules to firewall

Comment: @ Sumesh TG Sorry again, where to check it? The MySQL datanase is hosted at AWS with all default parameters and access from my Restful services API from localhost which is remote to AWS database services was success. However access from Resful secices at AWS tomacat to this database in not working. Do you think this firewall could be somewhere at AWS database services settings?

Comment: Ok i see.. Then this problem not related to firewall or database... Check the platform where you are trying to host this website

Comment: Check is there any missing library in the classpath

Comment: @ Sumesh TG The platform is Amazon web services: Elastic Beanstalk: there latest tomcat 8 in Linux (cannot see much details). I tryed to test with previous version of their tomcat: still not workied. Locally I use tomcat from Intellij IDE (and this one working). Do ou think I should try to change change AWS's libraries somehow?

Comment: sorry couldn't figure out your problem. include more screen shots and error codes if any. Thanks

Comment: @ Sumesh TG I actually know now what is the problem: and your guess was correct. the database is hosted at AWS and has Security group rules by default. in one of those rules I can see: "inbound" and ip address which is my internet provider address. I'm new and IP addresses thing is very unclear for me. But I guess it's somehow whitelist my provider address to my database so I can access it from when requst my localhost. Thus when requests from AWS server: it's rejected. Now I'll need to figure out how to allow access from everwhere. or at least from AWS IP.

Comment: @ Sumesh TG. And found: just change from "my IP" to "anywhere" in inbound rule: works now! If you could write it as answer: I'll be glad to accept it. (I don't want to answer my own question).

Comment: That's good. If you host the war in the same machine where your db also placed. then you just use localhost as the connection url in staging server remote url not required it may leads to security threats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A security group acts as a virtual firewall that controls the traffic for one or more instances. When you launch an instance, you associate one or more security groups with the instance. You add rules to each security group that allow traffic to or from its associated instances. You can modify the rules for a security group at any time; the new rules are automatically applied to all instances that are associated with the security group. When we decide whether to allow traffic to reach an instance, we evaluate all the rules from all the security groups that are associated with the instance.

Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Add an inbound rule to this security group will solve your issue.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: @F0XS Doesn't matter because the downvotes were placed so fast that the're catched as serial downvotes for sure. A nightly script will correct that votes and restore your reputation. If the revert doesn't happen until in 24 hours, open a meta post about it.

Comment: @chade_ Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add a comment: the confusion that I've got was caused by AWS' default setting in database which automatically whitelistes my IP in swequrities settings (Security group rules). Thus it allowed access to AWS hosted database from my computer when I run it at local Tomcat. I've changed it to access to "anyone" in "inbound" tab. That make access to AWS hosted Restful services to my AWS hosted database so it make it working.